# I want to retrieve location messages from whatsapp

Tags: location, message, whatsapp

I am trying to programmatically parse the location messages from whatsapp.
I cant even find out where they are!

I have location where the data theoretically should be stored ie in the Media directory, I find the images and the text messages just fine - but no locations.
I can send this location to other apps - but they dont like to show me the actual data.
I see that there are some encrypted databases that hold conversation history - is the location data parked there?

I cant imagine that I'm the first person who would like to do this.
Cracking the data i suspect is trivial, I'm not even able to find it!

Any recommendations?